# How do I get my text to line up with my image

Tags: html, css

So in the content section of my website, I have a section with daily highlighted projects. Each one of them has a thumbnail with a small preview, a head, and a short description. The link to the page is both the thumbnail and the head, while the description is not clickable.

The problem is my text shows up at the bottom right of the thumbnail, while it should just vertically line up with it. How do I make it move up so it goes under the head and to the right of the thumbnail?

[image: The problem]

```css
#highlights {
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}

#highlights p {
 margin-left: 90px;
 margin-right: 30px;
}

#highlights img {
 vertical-align: top;
 border: 1px #00366C solid;
 margin-left: 5px;
}

#highlights h1 {
 display: inline;
 color: #00366C;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 10px;
 background: none;
}

#highlights a {
 color: #00366C;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://gamingw.net/games/632">
    <img height="65" src="images/game-632.jpg" width="80">
    <h1>Coastercraft Gold</h1>
</a>
<p>
    Enter the World of CoasterCraft. Builds rides, hire staff and do all sorts 
    of other Theme-park managemently-things in this fun and refreshing game.
</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

My personal approach would be to change up the markup a bit and not wrap the image and heading in a single anchor. I would also float the image and the text content to get them to align properly.

```css
.project > a,
.project-text {
  float: left;
}
.project-text {
  padding: 5px;
}
.project-text h2 {
  margin: 0 0 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="project">
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
  </a>
  <div class="project-text">
    <h2><a href="http://google.com">Project Heading</a></h2>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Demo [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hungerstar/91gdp55h/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? I just made the image `float: left` and adjusted some margins.

```css
#highlights {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
}
#highlights p {
  margin-left: 90px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
#highlights img {
  margin-top: 7px;
  float: left;
}
#highlights h1 {
  margin-left: 90px;
  color: #00366C;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  background: none;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
#highlights a {
  color: #00366C;
}
```

```html
<div id="highlights">
  <a href="http://gamingw.net/games/632">
    <img src="images/game-632.jpg" width="80" height="65">
    <h1>Coastercraft Gold</h1>
  </a>
  <p>Enter the World of CoasterCraft. Builds rides, hire staff and do all sorts of other Theme-park managemently-things in this fun and refreshing game.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You floated the whole #highlights, but not the image itself.

Necessary changes below

```
#highlights img {
  vertical-align: top;
  border: 1px #00366C solid;
  margin-left: 5px;
  float: left; //Add this line
}
```